# unix sockets - can't connect to server (connection timed out)

Tags: c, sockets, unix, network-programming, ip

I try to create simple client\server program, based on UNIX network sockets.

There is code for server

```
/* Headers */
#include "common/service.h"
#include "net/protocol.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    /* Setting up socket */
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    $( sock < 0, "socket", NULL );

    struct sockaddr_in srv_address, cli_address;

    memset((char *) &srv_address, 0, sizeof(srv_address));
    srv_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    srv_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    srv_address.sin_port = htons(RKP_RL_DEFAULT_PORT);

    $(
        bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &srv_address, sizeof(srv_address)) < 0,
        "bind", NULL
    );
    /* Listening */
    listen(sock, 1);
    /* Accepting */
    int ca_len = sizeof(cli_address);
    int cli_sock = accept( sock, (struct sockaddr*) &cli_address, &ca_len );
    $( cli_sock < 0, "accept", NULL );
    /* Processing */
    char accept_buffer[RKP_BUFFER_SZ] = {0};
    read( cli_sock, accept_buffer, RKP_BUFFER_SZ-1 );
    printf( "Incoming message: %s", accept_buffer );
    write( cli_sock, "OK", 3 );

    close(cli_sock);
    close(sock);

    return 0;

}
```

And code for client

```
/* Headers */
#include "common/service.h"
#include "net/protocol.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    $( argc != 2, argv[0], "Wrong syntax" );
    // argv[1] contains server address

    int port = RKP_RL_DEFAULT_PORT;
    int sock = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
    $( sock < 0, "socket", NULL );  

    struct hostent* server;
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    $( server == NULL, "gethostbyname", "Host %s not found", argv[1] ); 

    struct sockaddr_in srv_address;
    memset( (char*) &srv_address, 0, sizeof(srv_address) );
    srv_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    strncpy( (char*) &srv_address.sin_addr.s_addr, (char*) server->h_addr_list[0], server->h_length);
    srv_address.sin_port = htons(port); 

    $( connect(sock, &srv_address, sizeof(srv_address)) < 0, "connect", NULL ); 

    char accept_buffer[RKP_BUFFER_SZ];
    memset( accept_buffer, 0, RKP_BUFFER_SZ );  

    printf("Enter message\n");
    fgets( accept_buffer, RKP_BUFFER_SZ-1, stdin );
    write( sock, accept_buffer, strlen(accept_buffer) );

    memset( accept_buffer, 0, RKP_BUFFER_SZ );
    read( sock, accept_buffer, RKP_BUFFER_SZ-1 );

    printf( "Server answer: %s\n", accept_buffer );

    close(sock);

    return 0;

}
```

Then i start server and client with parameter `127.0.0.1`, `localhost`, and `192.168.0.1`. Both program use port 6662. After few seconds until start i have got error:

```
connect: Connection timed out
```

How i can fix that?

Comment: What are those `$(...)` for. This isn't C.

Comment: @alk dollar sign is just macro for my condition check function.
    #define $ CONDITION_CHECK

    int CONDITION_CHECK(int condition, const char* cmd, const char* str, ...) {
 
        /* ... */
 
    }

Comment: When you start the server, and call `netstat -tlpn` afterwards, do you see it in the list (bound to a port on a specific adress/port?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring this line:

```
strncpy( (char*) &srv_address.sin_addr.s_addr, (char*) server->h_addr_list[0], server->h_length);
```

[`strncpy()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strncpy.3.html) works on `0`-terminated `char`-array, C-"strings". As you want to copy binary data use [`memcpy()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) instead.

```
memcpy(&srv_address.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_addr_list[0], server->h_length);
```

---

Also if not on windows or some old UNIX this line

```
int ca_len = sizeof(cli_address);
```

should be

```
socklen_t ca_len = sizeof(cli_address);
```

To be sure what type the 3rd parameter to [`accept()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) is you want to consult your documentation.